Construct an empty proto message
Is there a simple way to initialize a proto message with empty fields in C++?
Example:
Message:
message CardInfo {
    string name = 1;
    uint32 amount = 2;
}

Print:
CardInfo {
    name: "",
    amount: 0
}


Protobufs are initialized with default values. Strings are empty and ints are 0.
Note, however, that default values might not be printed.
Try this:
CardInfo info;
std::cout << info.DebugString();


Ok, I create message, and I should use CopyFrom to set an empty field in my current message?

Your question does not mention any "current message" or copying.  This sounds like a separate question which will need some more context to answer.
